# what is the meaning of the '%' appeared at the end of Unix command output

Tags: command-line, zsh, output

May I know what does it mean when a '%' appears at the end of the output when I execute my code?

For example:

```
Hello,World%
```

Added:

I'm using Mac Os X iTerm2 zsh shell.

My code

```
echo 'Hello,World' | tr "\n" "\000"
```

I added the tr command to get rid of the newline at the end.

I'm using vim so I want to get the output without the newline just like if I'm using emacs.

Thank you.

Comment: Is `%` your shell prompt? Did you print a newline at the end of your output?

Comment: You could also have used `echo 'Hello,World' | tr -d "\n"` or, better, `echo -n "Hello,World"` or `printf "Hello,World"`. And yes, the `%` is your shell prompt. I don't see how using vim is relevant.

Comment: I should have mentioned, `tr "\n" "\000" doesn't just remove the newline, it replaces it with a null character. This will usually have no  effect if you're writing to the terminal, but it can matter, particularly if you're writing to a file or to a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

The `%` is your standard prompt.

Normally this will appear on a line on its own

However this depends on the program you just run to end with a LF character.  Most commands do this automatically

eg

```
% echo hello
hello
%
```

However commands don't *have* to do this.  In this case your prompt gets added to the end of the line:

```
% printf "hello"  
hello%
```

In your case you removed the `\n` from your output with the `tr` command, and so the prompt appears on the same line.

We can demonstrate this by running your command twice, on the same line:

```
% echo 'Hello,World' | tr "\n" "\000" ; echo 'Hello,World' | tr "\n" "\000"
Hello,WorldHello,World%
```

Comment: No, in the case of `zsh`, it's not. See the dup question.